# How to change images of buttons on focus or unfocus?

Tags: jquery-mobile

can you please tell me how to change images of button on focus and unfocused in jquery mobile.

I need to change images when it is button is focus and when button is unfocus .so that user identify which button is selected  than  which is not..?

Thanks

Comment: But i am using jquery mobile ..is there any other function in jquery mobile..!!

Comment: but i need to change same image on unfocus..!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use on focus event and on focus you can change css of image or image background

```
<input id="myButton" type="text" onfocus="
```

---

myFunction()">

```
function myFunction(){
    $('#myButton').css('background-image',new image)
}
```

using this you can change the pic of image. Hope it help